# Upload-File-Request from JS to different Server with Session authentication on the webserver

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session, upload

I really need help with a huge problem which is probably really simple to solve ...

Ive got a HTML form which contains a submit Button and an input element for uploading a file, the form and submit is then handled by Javascript as a FormData.

The form is send to a PHP-Script on a different server, which saves the imagefile as a blob into a MySql Server. The MySQL Server is located on the Same Server as the Script.

My problem is: you can Log in into my Website, authentication Works fine as  well. When you log in, a PHP Session is started and two Session variables are set, a boolean to Check If logged in and another one which stores the username. To authenticate everything and display only content that belongs to the logged in User, the Session variables are checked everytime.

Since the post request is made by Javascript and is sent directly to the PHP Script on the Other server, i cannot Check the Session variables to authenticate if the request is actually made by the User and is Not caused by Somebody who maliciously want to Change Data of Other Users. The Session is only for the User and the Webserver, and is not available on the Other Server.

I dont want to create a PHP Script to First authenticate on the Webserver and then send a request to Upload the File in the Other Server ...

Is There anyone who had similiar problems and can help me?

Comment: You say you don't want to create a PHP script to first authenticate - but you are going to need to authenticate _somehow_ before pushing the file data.  The question is - how does the person on the "different server" authenticate? Are they authenticated in some way when they are submitting the file form?

Comment: At first a Login-Form is used to Login with the username and Password which are stored in the Database. If the Users Inputs (Username,Password) Match the Data in the Database, they are authenticated and a Session ist started with the Said variables Set. After that every script Just Grabs the Username from the Session variable to for example Change the Users surname etc.

Comment: Can you maybe label one server "Server A" and another "Server B", and re-write the question (and your latest comment) to reference the different servers? While your comment makes sense, it's hard to know which server you're referring to.

Comment: Of Course I will do that, but right now im too busy and i will rewrite everything to make it better understandable tomorrow morning, thanks for your help i really appreciate it! Thanks a lot!